# Format/ Layout problem with Head and Foodline, erased picture doesn't show up

Tags: header-footer

I study, and I decided for myself to use LaTeX, out of many reasons everyone knows here ...

I created my own coversheet, everything was fine, Layout, etc. but then, my document-head&foodline disappeared and I can't find the problem. I'm certain it has something to do with my bound packages, if someone could help me, would be awesome!!!

For the sake of easy accessing my code, I used `\input` to bind the formats in a different file: (no code-problem)

I use sharelatex.com.

So here is my format.tex code:

```
\documentclass[twoside = false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\parindent0cm 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Links im Inhaltsverzeichnis 
\usepackage{setspace} % weiß noch nicht wofür das gut sein soll
\usepackage{lmodern} % Für das 'Antialiasing' der Schrift
\usepackage{amsmath} % Für die Formeln, welche nummeriert werden
\usepackage{amstext} % Für Text in der Formelumgebung 
\usepackage{float} % Für das genaue Platzieren von Grafiken und Tabellen mit der Option [H] dahinter.
\usepackage{ulem} % Damit man mit \uline Sachen unterstreichen kann
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % Damit man EPS-Vektorgrafiken einbinden kann
\usepackage{amssymb} % Für weitere Symbole es gibt leider keinen Guide
\usepackage{listings} % Für Dinge Hervorheben mit %\begin{lstlisting}
%\usepackage{color} % Für die Farben z.B. in den Überschriften
\usepackage{caption} % Für Zeilenumbrüche etc. in Bild-Unterschriften
\usepackage[a4paper,12pt,left=25mm,top=15mm,right=20mm,bottom=30mm, headtopline=0pt,headsepline=0.8pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} %Kopf- und 5Fußzeilen Paket statt scrpage2
\usepackage{subfigure}  %Um Dinge nebeneinander?
\usepackage{booktabs} % Für TABELLENFORMATIERUNG
\usepackage{colortbl} %Einfärben von Tabelle
\usepackage{blindtext} % Einfügen von Textbereichen
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Bildverarbeitungspaket
\usepackage{graphicx}% Bildverarbeitungspaket
\usepackage{textcomp} % weiß nicht genau das im text nochmal bringt...

%Start of my Headline
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark} %einfügen von Linien
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
    {
  \chead{\headmark} %the headmark does show up, but not the picture...
  \ohead{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{LOGO.jpg}}
  \cfoot{\pagemark}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I should care more about my grammar ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question.

First of all you have to load package `scrlayer-scrpage` with option `automark` and maybe option `headline`. Then you have to remove the braces which includes your settings for the header. If they are in braces, they are only local and all your changes does not affect the code outside the braces.

With `height=5cm` for your logo is really tall for the page header. You have to enlarge `headheight` and maybe you want to hide the really height of the logo.

Maybe the following helps:

```
\documentclass[
  headheight=3.5cm,
  headinclude
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}% only for dummy text and example images

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[
  headsepline,% line below page header
  automark% set marks for section
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that I have used `\ihead` for `\headmark`. If `\chead` would be used, it could overlap with the logo.

[image]

Comment: Very good. Thus eliminate your zero score. :-)